# Jquery event для динамического элемента

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть динамически создаваемый элемент, не могу применить к нему след. отслеживание элементов:

```
$(".pathInput")
    .on("keydown", acBindKey)
    .on("focus", acSearch)
    .on("click", acSearch)
    .autocomplete(acPathOptions)
    .autocomplete("enable");
```

Как быть?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document)
    .on('change', '.pathInput', function() { ... })
    .on('keyup', '.pathInput', function() { ... })
    .on('focus', '.pathInput', function() { ... });
```